# Autoinstall - the password and authorized-keys options doesn't work

Tags: 20.04, automation

I am trying set password and authorized-keys using the configuration below. But they never worked.

```yaml
identity:
    hostname: hostname
    username: username
    password: $crypted_pass
ssh:
    install-server: yes
    authorized-keys:
      - $key
    allow-pw: yes
```

This June 2020 thread highlighted exactly the same problem:
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/please-test-autoinstalls-for-20-04/15250/165

Would you know if this bug still continues?

Comment: Here: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/please-test-autoinstalls-for-20-04/15250
is mentioned that the info on how to specify the authorized keys, can be foundin the cloudinit documentation, because it belongs to cloudinit rather than autoinstall here:
And indeed, here it is:
https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html?highlight=ssh#configure-instances-ssh-keys

Answer (score 1):

I set up users via the Ubuntu auto-install cloud-into mechanism successfully.  The key for auto install is using the `user-data` portion of the cloud config file which is supplied to the Ubuntu instance  the first time it boots after the install.

```yaml
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1

user-data:
    disable_root: false 
    users:
    - default
    - name: alpha
      ssh-authorized-keys:
        - <your user public key here>
      sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
      groups: sudo
      shell: /bin/bash
```